# SQL query runs on SQL Server 2008 standard but not on enterprise

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm having a problem with a query running on SQL Server 2008 enterprise.
The query is an insert to a table from another but it checks that a record is inserted just once.
The query does something like this:

```
insert into A(...)
--complex select from table B as b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE id = b.id)
```

Edit: this query does the following:
If the "complex select" from B selects the record 45 (i.e. the record with id = 45) twice then the where is true for the first time record 45 appears, so it gets inserted in A.
Then the second time record 45 appears, the where condition is false, so it does not get inserted in A twice.

This query works fine on SQL Server 2008 standard edition, so I think the problem is a difference between the SQL Server versions (like a default set different or something)
I'm reading about the Maximum Insert Commit Size, but I'm not sure if that can be the issue.
There is no error message, the only visible error is that in standard I get record 45 once and in enterprise I get it twice.
Any Ideas?

Comment: What is it doing or not doing that you are trying to fix?

Comment: I updated the question to answer your questions

Comment: Can you show all of the SQL statement? It might make it easier for others to understand what is going on/going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the behaviour you say you are getting on Standard Edition is for some other reason than you think it is.

You seem to be expecting that if your values to be `INSERT`ed contain duplicates that one will be `INSERTED` and then the `NOT EXISTS` will evaluate to false because of the existence of the newly added row. However AFAIK that is not the way it is supposed to work. Looking at a simple `INSERT .. SELECT` as below.

```
CREATE TABLE A(id INT PRIMARY KEY)

CREATE TABLE B(id INT PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO A
SELECT *
FROM B
```

Gives the following plan

[image: Simple Select]

Adding the `NOT EXISTS` clause

```
INSERT INTO A
SELECT *
FROM B
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE id = B.id)
```

Changes the plan as follows

[image: Sub query]

As well as the plan now including an anti semi join SQL Server has added an eager spool to the plan before the clustered index insert on `A`. This is a blocking operator and the purpose of it is to ensure that the entire `SELECT` is evaluated before any rows are inserted to `B` at all (Related to [Halloween Protection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2008/02/27/halloween-protection.aspx)).

You might not necessarily see a spool in your plans however. e.g. SQL Server might also choose to use another blocking operator such as a `SORT` or a hash anti semi join.

Please post the execution plan for at least the standard edition and preferably both. Also the queries so we can see if you are using any undeterministic constructs.

Answer (score 0):

try restructuring your query and see if it works. Instead of the `NOT EXISTS` join the tables in the insert query:

```
INSERT A(...)
SELECT ... FROM B LEFT JOIN A ON B.id = A.id
WHERE B.id = 45 AND A.id IS NULL
```

then you are performing the select only once.

Comment: The problem is that the whole query is generated at runtime, so introducing that change would be difficult. Besides, the query works, but only on sql server standard (that was the environment I had available); the real issue here is why it doesn't work on enterprise...